# Registration form with profile's field

Tags: django, django-forms, registration

I have a simple question. This is my profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    born = models.DateTimeField('born to')    
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo')
```

I want to create a **registration form** with these fields (from `User` and `Profile` models):

- username
- first_name
- last_name
- born
- photo

These fields are required.

How do I do that?

How does `get_profile()` work in a template for this issue?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Setup**

Are you using the [django-profiles](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/wiki/Home) and [django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home) projects?  If not, you should—much of this code has already been written for you.

**Profile**

Your user profile code is:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    born = models.DateTimeField('born to')    
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo')
```

Have you correctly setup this profile in your Django settings?  You should add this if not, substituting `yourapp` for your app's name:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "yourapp.Profile"
```

**Registration Form**

`django-registration` comes with some default registration forms but you specified you wanted to create your own.  Each [Django form field defaults to required](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/fields/#required) so you should not need to change that.  The important part is just making sure to handle the existing registration form fields and adding in the profile creation.  Something like this should work:

```
from django import forms
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from yourapp.models import Profile
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile

class YourRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    born = forms.DateTimeField()
    photo = forms.ImageField()

    def save(self, profile_callback=None):
        new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
        password=self.cleaned_data['password1'],
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'])
        new_profile = Profile(user=new_user, born=self.cleaned_data['born'], photo=self.cleaned_data['photo'])
        new_profile.save()
        return new_user
```

**Bringing it together**

You can use the default `django-registration` templates and views, but will want to pass them your form in `urls.py`:

```
from registration.backends.default import DefaultBackend
from registration.views import activate
from registration.views import register

# ... the rest of your urls until you find somewhere you want to add ...

url(r'^register/$', register,
    {'form_class' : YourRegistrationForm, 'backend': DefaultBackend},
    name='registration_register'),
```