# Django 1.8+ extending the User model

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-registration

I know this question has been asked hundreds of times, but most of them contain -accepted- answers that are not valid anymore. Some of them are for Django 1.5, some of them are even older.

So I'm looking for an up-to-date answer. The question that most resembles my problem is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764248/extending-the-user-model-with-django-registration).

I'm using the `django-registration` module and I want users to have additional fields (like integer `user.points`). I'm OK with implementing my own `MyUser` model and changing the rest of my program accordingly. However I doubt this will work in compliance with the registration module. So I guess the ideal way would be keep using the `User` model, and somehow tie them so that whenever a `User` object is created, a corresponding `MyUser` object is created with the default values for additional fields.

-How- can I do this with Django 1.8+?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: It doesn't change between Django 1.5 and 1.8 so linked answer isn't obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An article about the topic: [How to Extend Django User Model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)

What I use is the `One-To-One` approach:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
    #more fields

    @staticmethod
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid="at_user_post_save")
    def user_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        #create new profile on user.save() (if necessary)
        profile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)


#in view
profile = request.user.profile
```

**UPDATE:**

> Are there any other caveats? Like what happens when I remove a
>   UserProfile?

`UserProfile` is the one who holds the relation, so **on delete** no `user` should be deleted. You can control what must be the behavior when a `user` gets deleted via the [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) kwarg.

> Also do they always have the same private keys?

No each class have its own PKs, just the `UserProfile` holds the PK to its `user`.

`OneToOneField` is in conceptually a `ForeignKey` with an `unique=True`, the big difference is that the reverse side of the relation do not return a list with 0/1 elements, but the element itself or raise `DoesNotExist` or `None` if `null=True`.

The only thing which I don't like in this approach is that you always have to do 1 more query to get `user.profile`. I still can't find a good and clean approach to always `.select_related('profile')` when a new `user` is fetched from `auth`, but this is more of a problem of the authentication system rather than the approach itself.

Comment: This method seems more suitable now :) Any objections?

Comment: I'm going with this approach. It creates the `UserProfile` as a `User` is created. I just need to get the user like `request.user.profile` in the views, but are there any other caveats? Like what happens when I remove a `UserProfile`? Is the corresponding `User` deleted too? Also do they always have the same private keys?

Comment: @halilpazarlama updated the question with some answers to your questions. I also posted a link to an article explaining the different approaches with their pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

`django-registration` supports custom user models, so it won't be a problem to create your own user model and use it with `django-registration`.

All you need to do is to create registration form based on `registration.forms.RegistrationForm` and then use it in `RegistrationView`. You also need to keep `email` and `is_active` fields from default django user model and provide `email_user` method in user model. `USERNAME_FIELD` also must be specified. Other requirements depends of your authentication method.

More on that you can find in [`django-registration` docs](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.2/custom-user.html).

Answer (score 1):

First req for extending the user model: you have to start with a clean django project that you have not called the: "python manage.py migrate" command on.

This is because if you **did** migrated in the past, the un-extanded user model is already created an django doesn't know how to change it.

Now, to choose another user model the first thing you have to do is on your settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'APPNAME.Account'
```

It is recommended to create a new app to handle the user model. be aware not to call the app "account", as it collides with the already existing user model.

I created An app called accountb. on the models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class AccountManager(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')
        if not kwargs.get('username'):
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid username.')

        account = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), 
            username=kwargs.get('username'), 
            year_of_birth = kwargs.get('year_of_birth'),
            #MODEL = kwargs.get('MODEL_NAME'),
        )
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        account = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)
        account.is_staff = True
        account.is_superuser = True
        account.save()

        return account

class Account(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    #ADD YOUR MODELS HERE

    objects = AccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Also, dont forget to register it on admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Account

admin.site.register(Account)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This seem to work fine, but I'm just confused about the last part (registering it on `admin.py`) if I do it the way you proposed, I don't see the new fields. When I register it simply by `admin.site.register(Account)`, now I see the new fields. I wonder why is this happening. I will accept your answer anyway but I would appreciate collaboration about this too. Thanks again to all the answerers!

Comment: Now the registration module is giving me an error. If you are interested, here is my follow up [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155777/custom-user-models-in-django-no-such-table-auth-user) :)

Comment: My bad, that last part was some unrelated code. I edited my answer.