# Custom user models in Django: `no such table: auth_user`

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-registration

According to the answer to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153280/django-1-8-extending-the-user-model/40153862#40153862), I edited the django-registration module with the following modifications:

in `myapp/models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class AccountManager(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')
        if not kwargs.get('username'):
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid username.')

        account = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), 
            username=kwargs.get('username'), 
            #year_of_birth = kwargs.get('year_of_birth'),
            #MODEL = kwargs.get('MODEL_NAME'),
        )
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        account = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)
        account.is_staff = True
        account.is_superuser = True
        account.save()

        return account

class Account(AbstractUser):
    #email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    points = models.FloatField(default = 100.0)
    #ADD YOUR MODELS HERE

    objects = AccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Account: "+self.username
```

and in `myproject/settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.Account'
```

now the rest of the application works (i.e. refers to `Account` which also has base fields from the `User` model). However, the `django-registration` module itself is not working now. When I send a new registration form (with username, email and password), I get the error:

```
OperationalError at /accounts/register/
no such table: auth_user
```

I tried a lot of combinations of `makemigrations` and `migrate` (also with `--fake` and `--fake-initial` arguments) but (I guess) the `auth` table is not initializing with the new settings.

How can I fix this so I can keep registering with the new `Account` model while not harming the default `auth` module's `User` model?

Thanks for any help,

### Edit

When I tried to see the users in shell, I got this error which makes things a little bit clearer:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> users = User.objects.all()
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'myapp.Account'
```

So it looks like my new model `Account` has overwritten the default `User` model. If so, why is the registration module looking for the `auth_user` table? Doesn't the modification in `settings.py` aim to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't swap user model for any app that refers to it, if migrations for that app have been applied. Try to re-create your database by creating new one, reapplying migrations on it and then moving data from old database

Comment: I'm using sqlite and I removed the database file, re-created it. re-made migrations and migrated everything.. but maybe I'm missing something more basic. I decided to go with another way of extending the user model anyway. Sorry for the question is too vague. I'm considering of removing this question. But thanks for your help!